# Multiple facebook sites based on same app

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook app with localhost, production, and testing enviroments needs.

Facebook App domains:

- example.dev // localhost development OK
- example.com // production enviroment OK
- acme-staging.com // not allowed in FB dev dashboard!

Facebook Website->Site URL
 - http://example.com

Acme-staging.com is not allowed as it is not present in Website->Site URL. However, I cant create more websites why I had to resort to sending the dev branch to example.com/staging. Thats is a bad fix for us. How can we fix this?

Comment: Use test apps instead of one app. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps

Comment: unfortunately thats old docs, I cant find the feature!

Comment: Click on the App name in the upper left corner on the app settings page